# Suppose that $A ⊆ A × A$. Show that $A =∅$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Suppose that $A ⊆ A × A$. Show that $A =∅$
> Hint: Using axiom of regularity.

My proof.

Suppose that $A ⊆ A × A$ and $A\not=∅$. let $x∈A$.
Since $A ⊆ A × A$, $x∈A×A$ which implies $(x,∅)∈A×A \Rightarrow x∈A \mid x∈∅$ which is a contradiction $\Rightarrow 
A \not⊆ A × A$. But this contradicts our supposition, hence $A=∅$.

I don't know how to use axiom of regularity here.Also, please suggest how do i improve my proof if its correct. If not correct suggest the proof itself.

Comment: Why should $(x,\varnothing)\in A\times A$?

Comment: The inclusion A ⊆ A × A is like stating that all bachelors are a subset of the set of all married couples. It just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @BernardMasse It makes complete sense. It just can't happen to non-empty sets in ZF set theory because of the axiom of regularity (one purpose of which is precisely to prohibit pathological things like $A\subseteq A\times A$, or $X\in X$, and instead make all sets, well, regular).

Answer (score 3):

The step

> x∈A×A which implies (x,∅)∈A×A

is wrong.  I don't know why you think this is true because you didn't write any justification in your proof.

If $x∈A×A$ then $x$ is an ordered pair of elements of $A$ (definition of $A\times A$), so we can write $x=( y,z)$ for some elements  $ y,z$ of $A$.

At this point you probably need to apply the definition of an ordered pair and identify $x$ as a particular set. Can you do that?

Answer (score 1):

If $x\in A\subseteq A\times A$, then by definition $x$ has the form $\{\{y\},\{y,z\}\}$ for some $y,z\in A$. So $x$ is an element of $A$ which is also a subset of $2^A$ (power set of $A$). This is only fulfilled by the empty set $A=\emptyset$.

Comment: We don't know that OP knows that $x = \{\{y\}, \{y,z\}\}$ because we don't know what definition of ordered pair they are using.

Comment: If you come from logic and set theory to study math, some form of definition of the ordered pair is necessary (what kind of data structure the ordered pair is).

Comment: I agree that OP must be using _some_ form of definition of the ordered pair.  My point is that they didn't say what definition they are using.  It could be the Kuratowski definition you assumed, or it could be something else.

Answer (score 0):

By the short definition of set pairs (you can find it here [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Kuratowski's_definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Kuratowski%27s_definition)), we have $$(a,b)=\{a,\{a,b\}\}.$$

Then, using axiom of regularity, if $A\neq\emptyset$ and $A\subseteq A\times A$ we could find $x\in A$ s.t. $$x\cap A=\emptyset$$
and s.t. $$x=\{a,\{a,b\}\}$$ for certain $a,b\in A$.

But then $a\in x$ is a contradiction.

Comment: That is not Kuratowski's pairing.

Comment: I know, I wrote it is not.